# calling a function within another one

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I'm learning to code and am trying to learn to use functions more and more. I have 3 different functions here, and I haven't progressed far with the **user_menu()** function as I get stuck with the last piece of code in the if statement/construction.

The **times_table()** function keeps repeating itself no matter what I do or what code I add. It stays on that last line of the **if statement** in the **user_menu()** function. What can I do to remedy this?

I would also like to add the **times_table2()** function to the **user_menu()** function just under the **times_table()** function.

I would also like to ask for recommendations on how to combine the two times_table() functions into a single function whilst keeping the functionality. I haven't come across an example online or in the book and it's quite frustrating to be very honest.

I would appreciate some info and possibly some websites for more resources.

Regards and thanks in advance.

```
def user_menu():
    options = ["1. Would you like to learn to multiply two numbers of your choice?",
               "2. Would you like to learn to multiply a number in a table?"]
    print(*options, sep="\n")

    user_input = int(input("Please select from the list above: "))
    if user_input == 1:
        times_table(multiple="Please enter the number you wish to learn to multiply with")





def times_table(multiple):
    while True:
        multiple_text = input(multiple)
        try:
            multiple_int = int(multiple_text)
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a numerical value!")
            continue
            return multiple_int
def times_table2(multiple):
    while True:
        multiple_text = input(multiple)
        try:
            multiple_int = int(multiple_text)
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a numerical value!")
            continue
            return multiple_int
```

Comment: Are you using a Python debugger and/or IDE, or just editing text files and running Python from the command-line?

Comment: `times_table2` looks exactly the same as `time_table`. Is there supposed to be a difference between them?

Comment: I don't think it makes much sense to put a `return` immediately after a `continue`, because the `continue` will skip the `return` and go back to the top of the loop. What happens if you de-indent your `return` statements by one level?

Comment: You should try to make a minimal example of your problem. You've asked several questions in this one question, which makes it very hard to answer. Your actual engineering problem is the `return multiple_int` should be dedented to happen outside (and after) the `try/except` block. Your design questions are unclear, since `times_table` and `times_table2` appear to be identical.

Comment: Notably if you have an IDE (even an IDE-lite like my preferred editor VSCode), it might catch this error as seen [in this screenshot](https://imgur.com/hDyX9Dh) of nearly identical code.

Comment: Regarding times_table() function repeating itself no matter what, you just need to break out of the loop. Try changing `multiple_int = int(multiple_text)` to `return int(multiple_text)` to exit when successfully parsed. Your `except` block can just be the `print` line itself.

Comment: @dai, I'm using the Python IDLE but I have Thonny and VS 2019.

Comment: @AdamSmith I didn't think that the `return` should be outside of the `try/except` block as I was just constructing the entire function using the example in the book. I apologize for the multiple questions. I will take note to use more concise and smaller examples.

Comment: you should use `return multiple_int` before `except` - when you have correct value. OR you would have to use `break` before `except` to exist `while` loop and then use `return multiple_int`

Comment: @Ruzihm No there isn't supposed to be a difference between them as they are both input values for a simple multiple using user fed input. If you have a suggestion on how to combine them into a single function, I would highly appreciate it as I don't get it right to combine the two **functions** into a single 1.

Comment: @Kevin Dedenting the `return` statement did help for both `functions`, and the it works accordingly. Thank you for the advice!

Comment: @furas I was busy commenting on the other peoples suggestions, I didn't think you could do it in the fashion you suggested as the book I'm working through always has the `return` statement after the `continue` and indented the same as the `continue` within a loop, etc.... Is there a place I may refer to for more information on syntax?

Comment: @David An interesting idea, I didn't know you could do that, I will try it out. Thanks!

Comment: You can do this in different ways - some of them don't need `continue` - as in my answer.

Comment: @furas I always thought the `break` statement came after you finish typing out the entire `exception` construction (or `loop` construction for that matter). I didn't know you could place the `return` statement just after getting the correct user input. I appreciate your example at the bottom.

Comment: `break` is used to exit loop (`while` or `for`) in any moment and not wait to its end. `return` is used to exit function in any moment and not wait to its end. BTW: `continue` can be also used in any moment inside loop (`while` or `for`).

Comment: Comments are not meant for discussion. Please take this discussion into [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201287/calling-a-function-within-another-one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `return` after you get correct value

```
def times_table(multiple):
    while True:
        multiple_text = input(multiple)
        try:
            multiple_int = int(multiple_text)
            return multiple_int
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a numerical value!")
```

Eventually use `break` to exist `while` loop and then use `return`

```
def times_table(multiple):
    while True:
        multiple_text = input(multiple)
        try:
            multiple_int = int(multiple_text)
            break # exit loop
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a numerical value!")

    # after `while` loop
    return multiple_int
```

---

**EDIT:** As I said in comment you can do it in different way. If you really need to use `continue` then do as @Kevin suggested

```
def times_table(multiple):
    while True:
        multiple_text = input(multiple)
        try:
            multiple_int = int(multiple_text)
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a numerical value!")
            continue

        # inside `while` but not in `except`
        return multiple_int
```

In second version you can also use variable `True/False` instead of `break`

```
def times_table(multiple):
    repeat = True
    while repeat:
        multiple_text = input(multiple)
        try:
            multiple_int = int(multiple_text)
            repeat = False # exit loop
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a numerical value!")

    # after `while` loop
    return multiple_int
```